# does UML allow multiple relations between 2 classes?

Tags: uml

I'm currently working on a .xml to .uml diagram converter, but you may also add relations/attributes/operations and change pretty much everything.
but drawing multiple arrows between 2 classes would cause one to override the other one pretty much, i guess that's not the intention

Is that allowed by UML? Because i can not really find an example on the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you can have several association between two classes.

You can find a practical example [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html), where an `account` has `borrowed` or `reserved` `books`.

For the more theoretical aspect, you need to understand that for a class `C`, every attribute `A` has a type `T`, and that this attribute could be replaced in the diagram with an association of `C` with class `T` (the name of the attribute being shown on the `T` side of the link):

[image]